# Tracking mouse input events

Tags: c++, winapi, sendinput

Currently using `SendInput(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE)` to simulate mouse movements.
`SendInput` adds a new mouse event to the thread input queue before being processed.

Is it possible to track/check if an specific event has actually been processed?

Tracking `WM_MOUSEMOVE` in `WndProc` is no option since it is possible for the user to issue non-simulated mouse movements at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to track/check if an specific event has actually been processed?

In general: No.

> `SendInput` adds a new mouse event to the thread input queue before being processed.

Well, no. `SendInput` places input events into the hardware input queue, where they get picked up by the raw input thread, and dispatched to the respective threads' input queues.

> Tracking `WM_MOUSEMOVE` in `WndProc` is no option since it is possible for the user to issue non-simulated mouse movements at the same time.

Correct. You can, however, install a [low-level mouse hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx), where you can identify injected input<sup>1</sup>. Injected input has one of the `LLMHF_INJECTED` or `LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED` flags set in the [MSLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970.aspx) structure's *flags* member.

A brittle solution that allows you to identify injected input in your application's window procedure's mouse message handlers is to pass a specific *dwExtraInfo* value through the [MOUSEINPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273.aspx) structure. This value can be queried in the message handler by calling [GetMessageExtraInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644937.aspx). It is unreliable, though, because the system uses those values, too. There is no range of values an application can use, that is guaranteed to not collide with values used by the system.

---

<sup>1</sup> *The low-level mouse hook runs, after input events are dequeued from the hardware input queue. The events have not been processed by applications or even placed into the respective threads' input queues at that point.*